# How to use inject to get sum of some AR collection?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

There is model Order with association OrderItem. I need to calculate order's cost, and I use for it the following code:

```
order_items.inject{ |sum, oi| sum += oi.value }
```

But as result I get OrderItem object, not Fixnum or something else. What do I wrong?

Comment: is value an `Integer` or a `Float` or `Bignum`, then you should be using ActiveRecord [`SUM`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/sum)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you pass initial value to [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), the first item of the collection is used (`OrderItem` in you case).; `OrderItem += OrderItem#value` returns OrderItem according to your question.

Try the following (explicitly pass the initial value as Fixnum `0`):

```
order_items.inject(0) { |sum, oi| sum + oi.value }
```

As bjhaid commented, it's better to use [`sum` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) provided by ActiveRecord if you dealing with ActiveRecord. (Does not require to fetch records)

```
OrderItem.sum('value')
```

Comment: It is better to use the active record query interface to calculate sum instead of `inject`

Comment: @bjhaid, Thank you for comment. I'll add that. I just wanted to explain the reason why OP get `OrderItem` instead of `Fixnum` when he/she use `inject`.

Comment: I just checked the += does not make a difference if its a `Fixnum` object he is working with e.g `(1..6).inject { |mem, var|  mem += var } # => 21`

Comment: I meant the `+=` would work on a `Fixnum` object as I showed with the example, `inject` defaults `mem` to 0 in the example if no parameter is supplied to `inject`

Comment: @bjhaid, QUOTE from the documentation I linked in the answer: *If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.*

Comment: @bjhaid, Try `(1..6).inject { |mem, var| p mem; mem += var }` and `(1..6).inject(0) { |mem, var| p mem; mem += var }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46140/discussion-between-bjhaid-and-falsetru)